# Create a search option in Power BI dashboard based on keywords table

Tags: search, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have two tables

1. With complete data, including a keywords columns. where keywords are comma separated (around 25 keywords)

[image]

2. Unique keywords extracted from the keywords column. (single column with each keyword in each observation)

[image]

Task is, based on the keyword in the second table, search the observations that have similar keywords and display on the report.

Looks something like this:

[image]

This is a filter, which is not fulfilling my task.

(or)

I am back of https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=a586deac-c465-48da-978b-30ac2a4a3245 this activity. if someone can provide any solution related to this, will be helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you try to achieve. If you want just filter some visualization by selecting one of the keywords then create a measure (returning 0 /1, and this we can use for the filter in visualization) using SELECTEDVALUE -> for grabbing selected slicer and pathcontains (you need to replace comas ", " to pipe "|"

https://dax.guide/pathcontains/